# Password protected Zip File only works with a specific library

Tags: c#, c++, zip, 7zip

I am working with a zip file that is password protected. I've got the password and am able to extract the contents only when I use a C++ zip library called `minizip-ng`, which appears to be the library that was used to create the zip. When I try to extract it with a C# library or zip program like 7zip/Winrar it doesn't work - when I try to look at/extract the contents of the zip it says "Bad Password", even though it works with that one C++ library

Ideally I'd like to be able to use C# to read/modify the contents of the zip file without having to extract it.

Any thoughts on this issue would be appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: *it doesn't work* - what does this mean? What program prepared the zip in the first place?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified better. When I try to look at/extract the contents of the zip it says "Bad Password", even though it works with that one C++ library

Comment: What C# library are you using? How do you pass the password to the library? Are there international (non-ASCII) characters in the password?

Comment: This is the password:
bJ2thyhRsN69jDD6

Comment: Can you post up a dummy zip and a password so we can try with our various zip programs? Maybe it was prepared with minizip-ng and is somehow broken or peculiar such that only minizip-ng can extract it

Comment: So far the only C# library that I've tried is SharpZipLib.

Comment: Some password libraries offer multiple encryption options, e.g. 7-zip allows ZIP-compatible encryption or AES. Does `minizip-ng` have multiple encryption modes?

Comment: It might be worth trying to unzip the file using only .NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-6.0

Comment: Here is a link to one of the zip file I am trying to extract. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rtHuyKyNUS8jg2UbjIIuJrpLfzvGyJCp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't know if .NET's System.IO.Compression will work because I don't believe it supports password protected zips.

Comment: Renaming your test file with the .zip file extension, Windows can open it just fine. That means there's an excellent chance .NET can also open it just fine. Note, though, minizip-ng library DOES support various encryption options. Files you encrypt with a password might use an option SharpZipLib doesn't support. https://github.com/zlib-ng/minizip-ng/tree/master/doc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240147/discussion-between-gurrenm3-and-eric-j).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments that were posted I was able to figure out the issue. As mentioned by several people, the C++ library that was used to create the zip file supports different encryption modes that 7zip and SharpZipLib don't support. I was able to open the file without issue by using B1 archive, a 7zip alternative that supports many encryption modes. Now I just need to find a C# library that supports the encryption mode as well.

Thanks again for all of the help

Comment: If you found helpful stuff, please let us know, @gurrenm3